# Accessing AVTech camera with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, ip-camera

Using IP address in IE `http://192.168.0.112/` and username: admin, I can access all connected cameras. No password is required.

I get error with

`VideoCapture cap("http://192.168.0.112:80");`

or

`VideoCapture cap("http://admin@192.168.0.112:80");`.

Any solution?

Comment: does this webpage `http://192.168.0.112:80` give you only a video? or html? You need to find the webpage that refers to only the video part... a lot of cameras have a flash interface and you may access the video stream via rtsp

Comment: @api55, html. In device config, I have found Media port 34567 and HTTP Port 80. `rtsp://192.168.0.112:34567` or `rtsp://admin@192.168.0.112:34567` inside cap gives same error.

Comment: that is weird, normally the rtsp port is 554... maybe something is a miss in the settings. Also, most of the camera needs extra get parameters....like channel, user, password and in some cases the page is like `/video`. I think you need to play with the settings and find how to get the stream, then OpenCV part will work

Comment: @api55, Next time I'll inspect the `hmtl` source for streaming links.